# Error while running project 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'

Tags: webdriver-io

Below error snippet :

const utils_1 = require("@wdio/utils");
^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/marthaprasanthinuthalapati/ReportingAppAutomation/mf-react-report-scheduler/node_modules/@wdio/cli/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/index.js from /Users/marthaprasanthinuthalapati/ReportingAppAutomation/mf-react-report-scheduler/node_modules/@wdio/cli/node_modules/@wdio/repl/build/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of /Users/marthaprasanthinuthalapati/ReportingAppAutomation/mf-react-report-scheduler/node_modules/@wdio/cli/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/index.js in /Users/marthaprasanthinuthalapati/ReportingAppAutomation/mf-react-report-scheduler/node_modules/@wdio/cli/node_modules/@wdio/repl/build/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/marthaprasanthinuthalapati/ReportingAppAutomation/mf-react-report-scheduler/node_modules/@wdio/cli/node_modules/@wdio/repl/build/index.js:38:17) {
code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
Node.js v18.17.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.